# Issue on running Ionic module

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to run an Ionic project shared by a friend.
When I run "ionic serve" I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Giuseppe\Desktop\project>ionic serve

ng.cmd run app:serve --host=localhost --port=8100
[ng] node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922
[ng]   throw err;
[ng]   ^
[ng] Error: Cannot find module 'sourcemap-codec'
[ng] Require stack:
[ng] - C:\Users\Giuseppe\Desktop\project\node_modules\magic-string\dist\magic-string.cjs.js
[ng] - C:\Users\Giuseppe\Desktop\project\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\workspace\json\writer.js
[ng] - C:\Users\Giuseppe\Desktop\project\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\workspace\core.js
[ng] - C:\Users\Giuseppe\Desktop\project\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\workspace\index.js
[ng] - C:\Users\Giuseppe\Desktop\project\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\index.js
[ng] - C:\Users\Giuseppe\Desktop\project\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
[ng] - C:\Users\Giuseppe\Desktop\project\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
[ng]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:15)
[ng]     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:763:27)
[ng]     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:991:19)
[ng]     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
[ng]     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Giuseppe\Desktop\project\node_modules\magic-string\dist\magic-string.cjs.js:3:22)
[ng]     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1102:14)
[ng]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1131:10)
[ng]     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:967:32)
[ng]     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:807:14)
[ng]     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:991:19) {
[ng]   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
[ng]   requireStack: [
[ng]     'C:\\Users\\Giuseppe\\Desktop\\project\\node_modules\\magic-string\\dist\\magic-string.cjs.js',
[ng]     'C:\\Users\\Giuseppe\\Desktop\\project\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\node_modules\\@angular-devkit\\core\\src\\workspace\\json\\writer.js',
[ng]     'C:\\Users\\Giuseppe\\Desktop\\project\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\node_modules\\@angular-devkit\\core\\src\\workspace\\core.js',
[ng]     'C:\\Users\\Giuseppe\\Desktop\\project\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\node_modules\\@angular-devkit\\core\\src\\workspace\\index.js',
[ng]     'C:\\Users\\Giuseppe\\Desktop\\project\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\node_modules\\@angular-devkit\\core\\src\\index.js',
[ng]     'C:\\Users\\Giuseppe\\Desktop\\project\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\lib\\init.js',
[ng]     'C:\\Users\\Giuseppe\\Desktop\\project\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\bin\\ng'
[ng]   ]
[ng] }

        [ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).

        The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

So I try to install that module sourcemap-codec, through

```
npm install sourcemap-codec -> I get

C:\Users\Giuseppe\Desktop\project>npm install sourcemap-codec

up to date, audited 1689 packages in 5s

73 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

6 low severity vulnerabilities

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

But when I try to run, again, ionic serve, I get the same not found module error

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Have you tried deleting node_modules and reinstalling packages ?

Comment: Is there an easy way to install automatically all the needed packages?

Comment: I solved with a fresh installation of Ionic and Node.js